# typeerror 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, calculator

Basically, my code will input Equation: [equation] Code used： str(input('Equation：’））。 But once you type something in [equation]， there will be no error message, and no output.

Basically, the aim of the program I was making was to be able to easily convert an equation like a + b / c in the form of x (Basically simplificating the equation inputted).
However, if I typed  1 + 2 /1 （Simple example for the sake of not over complicating things), the output = nothing (No text, No error message)
For more context: I am new to python and VScode, so if it is not a coding error, it could be a VScode issue.
I understand that there may be a way simpler way to code this (Using import etc), but what im trying to do is understand what I did wrong, so I do not repeat this mistake in the future.

I have tried: renaming the variables, changing the variable types (int, float,even str as a last resort) , I have also rearranged the code, lastly also running it through GPT to see if it can detect my errors (No luck)。 Have also tried all of the suggestions so far, it doesn't fix the problem。
IDE = VScode

Edit : Its giving me a new error now: typeerror 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
at line 46. Im going to be busy, so I will not be responsive  for the next ~8=9hs. Will still appreciate feedback nonetheless. Sorry if my code is hard to understand, I currently do not have the time to make a (MRE). Have a good day :)

Updated code:

```
#Declarations
active = True #To keep it looping
active2 = False # To keep it looping2
listlen = int('0') #Length of the list equation
final = float('0') #Final printed value
single = int('1') #Placeholder for the value 1
operatorlo = int() #The location of the operator
operatortype = str('') #The type of operator
preval = int() #Value before the operator
afterval = int() #Value after the operator
equation2 = [] #List without ' / ' or ' * '
equation3 = []
def matchoperator(a,b):
    c  = all(item != a for item in b)
    if c:
        matchoperatorvar = True
    else:
        matchoperatorvar = False
    return matchoperatorvar
def lastvalue(a,b):
    if a == b(len) - 1:
        lastvaluevar = True
    else:
        lastvaluevar = False
    return lastvaluevar
def operatorbefore(pos1,pos2,list1,check1,check2):
    if list1[pos1] == check1 or check2 or list1[pos2] == check1 or check2:
        operatorbeforevar = True
    else:
        operatorbeforevar == False
    return operatorbeforevar



#Fundementals
equation = str(input('Equation:'))
equation = equation.replace('+',' + ')
equation = equation.replace('- ',' - ')
equation = equation.replace('*',' * ')
equation = equation.replace('/',' / ')
equation = equation.split()
#Locating position of operators
while active:
    for i in equation:
        if i == '*' or i == '/' or i == '+' or i == '-':
            operatorlo = equation.index[i]
            operatortype = i
            preval = float(equation[operatorlo -1])
            afterval = float(equation[operatorlo + 1])
            try:
                if i == '*' or i == '/':
                    if operatortype == '*':
                        newval = preval * afterval
                        equation2.insert('+')
                        equation2.insert(newval)
                    elif operatortype == '/':
                        newval = preval / afterval
                        equation2.insert('+')
                        equation2.insert(newval)
                    elif matchoperator('*' and '/', equation) == True and lastvalue(i,equation) == True:
                        active = False
                        active2 = True
                    else:
                        if operatorbefore(preval,afterval,equation,'*', '/') == False:
                            equation2.insert('+')
                            equation2.insert(operatortype)
                else:
                    if  matchoperator('*' and '/', equation) == True and lastvalue(i,equation) == True:
                        active = False
                        active2 = True
            except:
                print('Error in multiplication and division')
                active = False
while active2:
    for i in equation2:
        if i == '+' or '-':
            if equation2[0] == '+' or '-':
                del equation2[0]
            operatorlo2 = equation2.index[i]
            operatortype2 = i
            preval2 = float(equation2[operatorlo2 -1])
            afterval2 = float(equation2[operatorlo2 + 1])
            try:
                if operatortype2 == '-':
                    newval2 = preval2 - afterval2
                    equation3.insert('+')
                    equation3.insert(newval2)
                elif operatortype2 == '+':
                    for i in equation3:
                        final = final + i
                    print(final)
                    active2 = False
                elif matchoperator('+' and '-', equation2):
                    print(equation2)
                    active2 = False
            except:
                print('Error')
                active2 = False
```

Comment: Just pasting all your code into a question is unlikely to help. You need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That said, I see at least one problem. You replace the operators in your expression with space-padded ones, e.g. `' * '` for `'*'`, and then you have the statement `equation = equation.split()`. So far, so good. However, you then have tests like `i == ' * '`, which presume that the operators are still space-padded, even though the call to `split()` will trim away the spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that split() removes the spaces. Example: b = 1 + 3. I assumed that split(b) = [1, +, 3]. I will try troubleshooting that issue, Thanks :)

Comment: There are a ton of problems in this code.... `b(len)` should be `len(b)`, `'+' and '-'` is just `True` and does not do what you think it does, same with `if equation2[0] == '+' or '-'` that is not how you compare to multiple values, using `del` while iterating through a sequence.... I could go on